# How can I reference a YAML anchor from another YAML anchor?

Tags: yaml, anchor

I have a YAML file which has several different keys that I want to provide the same value for. Additionally, I want this value to be easily configurable.

See YAML for my specific use-case below:

```
--- 
# Options for attribute_value
att_value_1: &att_value_1
att_value_2: &att_value_2
# There could be more options...

# This is where the constant is being set.
attribute_value: &attribute_value *att_value1

items:
  - name: item1
    attributes:
      attribute_for_item1: *attribute_value
  - name: item2
    attributes:
      attribute_for_item2: *attribute_value
```

Here is a simplified YAML which demonstrates the problem:

```
--- 
foo: &foo "Hello World!"
bar: &bar *foo
```

Error (it's complaining about the first line that has "Hello World!" on it):

```
(<unknown>): did not find expected key while parsing a block mapping at line 2 column 1
```

I expect the value to propagate.

Answer (score 1):

> Error (it's complaining about the first line that has "Hello World!" on it):

You have to tell us which YAML implementation you're using. [PyYAML](https://yaml-online-parser.appspot.com/) and [NimYAML](https://nimyaml.org/testing.html) both correctly report that the error is in the third line; the second line is okay.

> I expect the value to propagate.

There is nothing in the specification that backs this expectation. [The spec says](https://yaml.org/spec/1.2/spec.html#id2786378):

> Note that an alias node must not specify any properties or content, as these were already specified at the first occurrence of the node.

*Properties* are anchors and tags. You cannot put an anchor on an alias node since it already has an anchor.

In your example,

```
---
foo: &foo "Hello World!"
bar: &bar *foo
```

`&bar` is completely superfluous since you already can refer to the `"Hello World"` node via `*foo` and therefore, there is no point in introducing `&bar`.

To answer your question: You cannot reference a YAML anchor from another YAML anchor, because a YAML anchor is not a node. YAML represents a *graph*, i.e. nodes and directed edges. Anchors and aliases are used to reference the same node multiple times (not to copy values as you might think). This also means that everything within a YAML file is content. There is no such thing as variable declarations.

It seems you are using the wrong tool for your use-case. To configure YAML files with external values, you would typically use a templating engine (SaltStack and Ansible use Jinja for example) and generate your YAML file from a template. You could supply your options in another YAML file. This would clearly separate the configuration options from the content.